# Why SWI-Prolog doesn't display 'false' when there aren't any more results to show

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm following a Prolog book and currently trying the following example.
My facts are;

```
parent(tom, bob).
parent(pam, bob).
parent(tom, liz).
parent(bob, ann).
parent(bob, pat).
parent(pat, jim).
```

I queried Prolog as:

```
?- parent(X, Y).
```

Results were;

```
X = tom,
Y = bob ;
X = pam,
Y = bob ;
X = tom,
Y = liz ;
X = bob,
Y = ann ;
X = bob,
Y = pat ;
X = pat,
Y = jim
```

Why Prolog doesn't show '***false***' at the end to show that there aren't anymore possible results?

Moreover, I tried following query. But it gave me different result which was unexpected, gives extra '***false***'.  Can you tell me what is the reason for that?

```
?- parent(Y,jim), parent(X,Y).
Y = pat,
X = bob.

?- parent(X,Y), parent(Y,jim).
X = bob,
Y = pat ;
false.
```

I'm using SWI-Prolog version (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.2.4).

Comment: It depends on how backtracking is performed (order of clauses, etc). In the first example, there is one Y and no other possibility. In the second, we backtrack and finally reach fallse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLD resolution, the Prolog's proof procedure,  implicitly defines a **search tree** of alternative computations.

Prolog searches this tree using a **depth-first strategy**, one branch at a time, backtracking when it encounters a failure node.

SWI-Prolog prints `false` only when the last node visited during the search is a failure node.

Considering the program:

```
parent(tom,bob). % parent.1
parent(pam,bob). % parent.2
parent(tom,liz). % parent.3
parent(bob,ann). % parent.4
parent(bob,pat). % parent.5
parent(pat,jim). % parent.6
```

The search trees are:

- First query:

[image]

- Second query:

[image]